# Pushed .nojekyll file to Github pages, no effect?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to push some Sphinx-generated docs to Github pages. I've found out that Jekyll removes the folders with an underscore; since I wasn't using it anyway I added a `.nojekyll` file to the folder, committed and pushed. However, nothing is happening yet. Did I do something wrong, does the process normally take some time, or should I force the page to rebuild in some other way? Thanks.

Comment: Did you rebuild your site locally before pushing up? Putting a `.nojekyll` fine in the root tells Github NOT to use jekyll to build your site. So you need to build it locally first - so there is the right content in your  output `_site` directory.

Comment: Also, Jekyll doesn't "remove" folders with an underscore. It uses their contents to build pages. When a folder does not have an underscore, Jekyll will copy that folder them over to the output`_sites` folder.

Comment: It worked now after another, uncorrelated commit & push. So I suspect it was just Github pages not rebuilding for whatever reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem was solved after another commit and push of a seemingly unrelated change. It was probably just Github pages not rebuilding the site and once a build was forced it was all fixed. Issue closed for me.

Comment: Ah, caching. Ever wonderful, ever a mystical headache, eventually consistent.

Comment: In my this case this didn't help and I contacted Github support. I'm now waiting for a response from them.

Comment: ...never mind, it turns out that my problem was unrelated to .nojekyll

Comment: FWIW, you can confirm if there's caching issues by copying the URL that the browser requested from into the terminal: `curl https://...`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error and I found the issue on github pages repo: 
 https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/315

**Answer**: just add the parameter `-t true` ...

**Example:**

```js
// Package.json
"deploy": "touch ./output_folder/.nojekyll && gh-pages -d output_folder -t true"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) package to autopublish and deploy a build (I'm building Astro locally with a database) to the `gh-pages` branch you can add the `--dotfiles` flag.

```bash
npm install gh-pages -D
gh-pages -d dist --branch gh-pages --dotfiles
```